# Is Possible to Show Different locations in different map frame?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've a question about google maps. I have different locations and I want to show on different maps on divided screen. But I could not. I could just show first location with map. As you can see at following screenshot, second map does not seen. Could you please help? I researched lots of source. But I could not find any answer.

Thank you

Screen:
[image]

Script Code:

```
function generateAtmsContent() {

var lines[{ latitude: "40.865787579814",longitude: "29.274772819435"},
          { latitude: "40.86427179754", longitude: "29.27419601979"}]
var lat;
var lng;
var divContent = '';
var atms;

var count = lines.length;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    atms = lines[i];

    lat = Number(atms.latitude);
    lng = Number(atms.longitude);
    

    divContent += generateAtmsRow(atms);
}
return divContent;
}


function generateAtmsRow(atms) {

var divContent = '';

divContent += '<div class="bubble table bubble-m grid-2">';

divContent += '<div class="mapWrapper">';
divContent += '<div id="map" class="map">';
divContent += '</div>';
divContent += '<div class="map-gradient">';
divContent += '</div>';
divContent += '</div>';

return divContent;
}

var map;
 window.initMap = function()  {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
        zoom: 12
    });
};

function loadMapScript() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.defer = true;
script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=keycallback=initMap";
document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: The `<div>` id must be unique.

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: not a number` (`lat` and `lng` are not defined).  Please provide a [mcve], preferably a Stack Snippet in the question, that demonstrates your issue, including some test data,

Comment: Hi @geocodezip, It is not about <div> id. Becuse code is working. Just as I mentioned at the question I want to show different location on different map frame.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with dynamic id for map in initMap function as following;

```
var map;
window.initMap = function()  {
 var mapIds = document.querySelectorAll('.map');
 
 for (var i = 0; i < mapIds.length; i++){
    mapIds[i].id = 'map-' + i;
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i],lng[i]);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapIds[i].id), {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 15
    });
}
```